# Dagger's dependency injection ignored, field remains null

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger

I have 2 modules: `AndroidModule` for providing `Context`-related objects and `PhotosModule` providing `PhotoManager`.

I want to use `PhotoManager` in `PhotosFragment`. `PhotoManager` depends on `DbManager`, which is provided by `AndroidModule`.

How do I connect all the dots?

The code compiles, but a NPE is thrown on this line:

```
mDbManager.readDatabase();
```

meaning that the injection of `DbManager` into `PhotoManager` did not occur, even though I set the

```
injects = PhotoManager.class
```

in `AndroidModule`.

Also, `mDbManager` is not a private field, so I don't think I have to use injection on `PhotoManager`'s constructor; field injection should be sufficient.

What's the reason and how do I satisfy the missing dependency? I assume there may be more than one problem with my code. Note: I just started with Dagger, please keep that in mind.

Application:

```
public class TestApp extends Application {

    private ObjectGraph mObjectGraph;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate(); 
        mObjectGraph = ObjectGraph.create(getModules().toArray());
    }

    protected List<Object> getModules() {
        return Arrays.asList(new AndroidModule(this), new PhotosModule());
    }

    public void inject(Object object) {
        mObjectGraph.inject(object);
    }
}
```

AndroidModule:

```
@Module(library = true, injects = PhotoManager.class)
public class AndroidModule {

    private final TestApp mApplication;

    public AndroidModule(TestApp application) {
        mApplication = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @ForApplication
    Context provideApplicationContext() {
        return mApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    DbManager provideDbManager() {
        return new DbManager(mApplication);
    }
}
```

PhotosModule:

```
@Module(injects = PhotosFragment.class)
public class PhotosModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    PhotoManager providePhotoManager() {
        return new PhotoManager();
    }
}
```

PhotoManager:

```
@Singleton
public class PhotoManager {

    @Inject
    DbManager mDbManager;

    public void doSomething() {
        mDbManager.readDatabase();
    }
}
```

PhotosFragment:

```
public class PhotosFragment extends Fragment {

    @Inject
    PhotoManager mPhotoManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ((TestApp) getActivity().getApplication()).inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ///...
        mPhotoManager.doSomething();
    }
}
```

DbManager:

```
@Singleton
public class DbManager {

    public DbManager(Context context) {
        //...
    }

    public void readDatabase() {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Right. I guess I should jump straight to Dagger2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the core of the problem: in `PhotosModule`, you have the provider method:

```
PhotoManager providePhotoManager() {
    return new PhotoManager();
}
```

You are `new`ing up the PhotoManager yourself, so Dagger doesn't have an opportunity to inject its dependency (the `DbManager`).

I think it's because you're misunderstanding the meaning of the `injects` property on the `@Module(injects=...)` annotation of the `AndroidModule`. You have:

```
@Module(library = true, injects = PhotoManager.class)
```

But that `injects` isn't needed, because you're never calling objectGraph.inject on the PhotoManager. Instead, you're only injecting the `PhotoFragment`, which is correct...

So one way to fix the NPE problem:

1. remove the `injects=PhotoManager.class` from `AndroidModule.java`:

   ```
   @Module(library = true)
   ```
2. change `PhotosModule` to include `AndroidModule`:

   ```
   @Module(injects = PhotosFragment.class, includes = AndroidModule.class)
   ```
3. I avoid field injection using the `@Inject` annotation (only use it for the top-level objects, i.e. where you do the objectgraph.inject, such as activity and fragment level), and use constructor injection instead for all the other dependencies. So I'd change `PhotoManager` to inject the `DbManager` like this:

   ```
   private final DbManager mDbManager;

   public PhotoManager(DbManager dbManager) {
       mDbManager = dbManager;
   }
   ```

I've put up the code [here on GitHub](https://github.com/glombard/so/tree/master/31687648_dagger/app/src/main/java/com/codeblast/dagger1app).

Comment: Great, clear answer. I was relying on that [Dagger's sample project for Android](https://github.com/square/dagger/tree/master/examples/android-simple/src/main/java/com/example/dagger/simple) way too much, the `includes` keyword is not even used there. Thanks a lot!